# Enable Macros in MS Access automatically for the user

Tags: vba, ms-access, office365, ms-access-2016

Office 365
MS Access
Enable All Macros automatically

I had a macro and vb script that ran the steps to enable all macros in MS Access for the user automatically.
A recent update put a stop to that.

Are there other options that would allow this feature as part of the installation process?

Tried adding local and network paths to trusted locations.

Comment: Trusted locations should work.

Comment: ?Recent update? Is this the recent security update where Office takes account of the "downloaded from Internet" flag?  Please check and clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manipulating the global macro settings, you can configure Office applications to trust specific locations on your computer or local network. Any Access file in a trusted location opens with macros enabled and without security warnings, even if the `Disable all macros without notification` option is selected in the `Trust Center` settings. This lets you run macros in certain files when all other Access macros are disabled.

1. Click File -> Options.
2. On the left-hand pane, select `Trust Center`, and then click `Trust Center Settings…` .
3. In the `Trust Center` dialog box, select `Trusted Locations` on the left side. You will see a list of the default trusted locations. These locations are important for the correct work of Access add-ins, macros and templates, and should not be changed. Technically, you can save your file/db to one of the Access default locations, but it's better to create your own one.
4. To set up your trusted location, click `Add new location…` .
5. In the `Microsoft Office Trusted Locations` dialog box, do the following:

   - Click the `Browse` button to navigate to the folder that you want to make a trusted location.
   - If you wish any subfolder of the selected folder to be trusted too, check the `Subfolders` of this location are also trusted box.
   - Type a short notice in the `Description` field (this can help you manage multiple locations) or leave it empty.
   - Click OK.
6. Click `OK` twice to close the remaining dialog boxes.

Comment: I tried that. Maybe I'm not doing it right. But it's not working.

Comment: Try to follow the steps posted. Do you save the file to the trusted location?

Comment: Also you may consider creating a COM add-in instead of VBA.